How do I check for a value efficiently in a list of dictionaries in Python?
Say I have a list of dictionaries:
universe_creatures = [
    {'type': 'dragon', 'weight': 1400},
    {'type': 'kraken', 'weight': 6000},
    {'type': 'elf', 'weight': 75}
]

How can I search if there's a certain type in one of the dictionary values in a shortly phrased code, but as efficient as possible?
What I currently have:
typ = 'dragon'
found = False

I believe for-loop is the most efficient because it iterates over once, and doesn't have overheads as generator calls do.
# for loop

for c in universe_creatures:
    if typ == c['type']:
        found = True
        break

But I'm looking for a shorter phrase, like the two below, and want to learn if the generator expression is too expensive compared to the for-loop above.
And I think generator is more efficient than list comprehension as the latter iterates over data more than once.
# generator expression

found = typ in (c['type'] for c in universe_creatures)

# list comprehension
# one iteration to create new list, then 'in' operator iterates again to search.

found = typ in [c['type'] for c in universe_creatures]


Did you try profiling these to actually see which is "more efficient"?

A for loop is only going to iterate once.  Why do you think it will do more than that?

Sounds like you want any(true for c in universe_creatures if c['type'] == typ)?

If you will be performing this test multiple times, where universe_creatures doesn't change but typ does, it might be better to collect the different types into something better suited for searching once, and use it for each search.

@MarkRansom I meant that list comprehensions iterate more than once. I rephrased it in question.

Again, the list comprehension only contains one for loop so it will only iterate once.  I don't understand why you believe it will be more.

"I think generator is more efficient than list comprehension as the latter iterates over data more than once" - where did you hear this / what makes you say this?

@MarkRansom @JRiggles It iterates to construct new list, then in iterates to search it. That makes two. Am I wrong here?

in a shortly phrased code, but as efficient as possible? please choose one

"Say I have a list of dictionaries:" Any chance you can change that to a dict of dictionaries? universe_creatures = {"dragon": {"type": "dragon", "weight": ...}}; then you can just do "dragon" in universe_creatures in O(1).

any(c['type'] == typ for c in universe_creatures). Anything better will require a different data structure that doesn't require a linear scan through universe_creatures.

FWIW: If you set up a basic benchmark test with the timeit module, you'll see that the list comprehension variant is actually slightly faster than the generator expression (by about 10mS over 100,000 runs). This likely isn't enough of an improvement to worry about in practice, but it seemed worth mentioning.

Thanks for the explanation, now your question makes sense.  And thanks for the comment in the question to explain it there.

@chepner thank you, sounds like the best available option, also Mathias R. Jessen for pointing it out too. @ScottHunter I thought of collecting types somewhere else, but universe_creatures can change, also trying to save memory, and do minimal iterations. @tobias_k creating a dict from it would require more iterations, my goal is to go over data least as possible. @JRiggles I know list comprehension is quicker, but I'm also trying to save up on memory. the list might be quite large.

@chepner your comment is good enough to be an answer.

@UpTheIrons To clarify, I did not mean creating a dict of dict from the list of dict each time before looking up a value (that would indeed be very wasteful and completely defeat the O(1) lookup), but just once, and using that instead of the list of dict in all places.

if by efficient you mean readable use @chepner answer. If by efficient you mean fast, if you are always going to look by creature type, simply set it as a dictionary key. e.g. creatures = {'dragon': {'weight': 1000, 'height': 100}, ...}

@tobias_k @Tarifazo But universe_creatures is what I get from a server. I am obliged to get this type of data structure more than once, an unpredictable number of times. That's why I'm trying to operate efficiently on it without changing it.

@chepner I just realized that the expression within your any() call is a generator expression. This makes it basically the same as the code with generator expression in my question. Plus, according to my speed comparison test, typ in (c['type'] for c in universe_creatures) is slightly faster than any(c['type'] == typ for c in universe_creatures)

speed comparison for reference, for all methods mentioned, 5 million iterations: for loop (1.15 seconds), in operator with list comprehension (1.50 seconds), in operator with generator expression (2.12 seconds), any function with generator expression (2.31 seconds).

If you have to use the data as-is, that's another matter of course. However, if you get this from a server, then the work for transforming it to a dict is probably negligible and might make the rest of your code faster or just more readable. Just saying.

A couple of other methods to try:
found = len([c['type'] for c in universe_creatures if c['type'] == typ]) > 0

or
any(filter(lambda c: c['type'] == typ, universe_creatures))

The upside of these approaches is that it is quite easy to get the dictionaries which match you criteria.

Inspired by @chepner
def logAndReturn(i):
    print("evaluating:", i)
    return i

found_return_immediately = any(logAndReturn(i) == 1 for i in range(3))
print("===separator===")
found_return_after_loop_end = 2 in (logAndReturn(i) for i in range(3))

output:
evaluating: 0
evaluating: 1
===separator===
evaluating: 0
evaluating: 1
evaluating: 2

Although, your search operation in a list is in the time complexity of O(n). If your list is really big, you should consider using other data structure like dictionary or say, a Hash Table
